# How do I write a code to remove the an element from an array and insert another element in its place

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have just started to learn functions and I am struggling to work out how to do a certain function.

How would I, write a code to remove the second element (22) from the array,

data=["text",22,"string","integer"]

and insert the element "number" in its place.

Hope you can help.

Thanks :)

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` may help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write functions, just treat it as a variable, and assigning a new value will overwrite the existing value.
data[0] is for storing first value.
data[1] is for second

if you need to change second value
just write a code as lex mentioned.

```
data[1]="new_value";
```

Comment: oh right so, it would be...

data=["text",22,"string","integer"];
data[1]="number"

Comment: yes.. :) . Also add a semi column after the second statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the new value to the correct index:

```
data[1] = "number"
```

If you don't know the index, you can find it with `data.indexOf(22)`:

```
data[data.indexOf(22)] = "number"
```

Comment: so i literally just type
data[data.indexOf(22)] = "number"